# notepad++ regex custom length word wrap macros

Tags: regex, automation, notepad++, word-wrap, text-formatting

The time of day that you have missed. Recently I began to study the expressive expressions, but the task before me is too complicated.

I think many people need the ability to quickly format texts of almost any type. Problem is not easy and I hope to get a solution to this problem from professionals.

If you use a limited breakdown for each line, then only large lines are broken which is much better. That is, to break only those lines that are larger than a certain size and which are more or less evenly broken Correct formatting of the text is quite Difficult to take into account a lot, I will go out for a long time. As you can see, there are small lines and they have to be sent back by connecting the previous line, but the problem is. And again have to apply formatting. But it is unclear whether this new formatting will create new problems.

All this is write in the macro via notepad ++ one after another and use.

However, it is necessary to solve the most important problems:

It is important to 
I want to immediately note: textFX does not offer. My attempts to write a macro with textFX (including attempts with 75 or a number from the clipboard failed, the text was written with unreadable code), I sent a corresponding message to the site notepad ++ a day ago

Use a regular point also do not offer. The fact is that notepad ++ macro does not understand the point of replacing the indentation with spaces by default 4pcs. (Yes, the macro must also indent the text, but this is all right)

About soft wordwrap (not formatted just click) is also not worth talking about.

Comment: I have no idea what you're looking for. What exactly is the task you want to accomplish with regular expressions? Please also [edit] and format your question, right now it's just a wall of text. You can use code blocks (`\``) around your regular expressions and `---` for line breaks.

Comment: Please format your answer. Format the code as code, data as data, make the hyperlinks into actual hyperlinks etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

inscrease line indent 2-4

split lines

descrease line indet 2-4

^(.?)$\s+?^(?=.^\1$) null

2017 (\d+:\d+) 17

subscribe .+$ null

(^.{1,30}$)\R \1

\r\r\n \n

^ spaces\1

i create macro and solved more problems